# What's this usage of the variable cast to void in function body?

Tags: c++, function, casting, function-parameter

I am just learning to code embedded C.  I see some code like below.

The function is defined like this:

```
void printDebug(const char d1[]){(void)d1;}
```

And it is used like this:

```
printDebug("BLE_UART_EVENT");
```

I don't understand its purpose. It gives me an impression of a callable `char` array?

Comment: What do you mean by "char array is callable"? Which part of this code do you believe is "calling" a char array? In case you wonder, `printDebug` as shown is a no-op; it's not clear what the point of the exercise is.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Honestly speaking, the `(void)d1;` part. But actually I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: This is just a type cast

Comment: It's a type cast that does nothing. It simply suppresses "unused parameter" warning. Nothing is being called here.

Comment: It looks like it may be a placeholder function for code than has yet to be written or perhaps a *null* function alternative for when debugging mode is turned off. Just guessing but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It's a workaround for a compiler warning on code that's valid and meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not calling `char` array, it's just explicitly converting the `char` array to `void`. (And the evaluated result is discarded immediately.)

I think it's just used to prohibit the compiler warning of unused variables.

If the parameter won't be used at all, it would be clearer to make it an unnamed parameter.

```
void printDebug(const char[]) {}
```

Comment: So I think maybe the `printDebug` function is not fully implemented yet. And thus needs to suppress the unused parameter warning.

Comment: @smwikipedia I suppose there will be another implementation for the debug build which actually do print it somewhere. But for release build it's pointless to print debug info.

Comment: @smwikipedia Maybe. But it's still a bad idea. If it's not used, it should be unamed.