# What's the purpose of void in a function invoking?

Tags: c, void

I see below code (with some omission):

```
int fwts_fault_catch(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)fwts_fault_catch(); // <======== HERE
    //...
}
```

So it seems the function invoking explicitly overrides the return type of the declared function prototype from `int` to `void`. Why doing this?

I did some test with below code:

```
int func1(void){
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    func1(); // line 2
    (void)func1(); // line 1
}
```

I check the assembly code generated with gcc for line 1 and 2 respectively. But there's no difference.

So, what's the `(void)` for?

Comment: A developer's acknowledgment that he/she has ignored the return value

Comment: ...otherwise lint-type tools that scan code for validations can/will flag it as a potential logic problem.

Comment: Note that you asked a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307858/whats-this-usage-of-the-variable-cast-to-void-in-function-body) just a few days ago.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I didn't realize that question is similar to this. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes, both usage have a pedantic smell.